# What is the shiny structure under a metal coating?

Tags: metallurgy

I performed a hot dip aluminizing on steel for 15 seconds. Then, after I bent the steel to remove the coating easier, the steel under was rough, shiny, and metallic, and was different from the original steel.The layer seems to be random and has bumpy structures. I can't mechanically removed the layer. I couldn't have analyze it chemically. Could I conclude that it is an intermetallic layer of Al and steel?[image: Picture]

Comment: Comment not answer because I am not sure of what is. But I suggest to look for something like thermite reaction. How does it sound? It should loose is shine more or less soon

Comment: Based on my readings, thermite reaction involves Al and rust. But before I hot dip aluminize the steel, I cleaned it first with HCl to remove rust, so the metals involve is mostly the steel itself and Al. Would the process still affects the shiny appearance?

Comment: No, it is was just a plausible suggestion. I was thinking about a "cleaning" of the steel, but if you treated with HCl then no.

Answer (score 1):

Likely an intermetallic , I think there are a couple different ones. I am more familiar with "spray and diffuse"  or vapor deposition ( Alon). Alonizing is very long ( > 24 hr) but gives a high integrity coating , can't remember the thickness.  As I remember the "diffuse" cycle takes a couple hours. I expect your process produced a thinner coating but still with some intermetallics.

Comment: Is these process related if my dipping time is only 15 secs?